# SQL Server Configuration Manager is not showing SQL Services

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2017, configuration-manager

I have newly installed following things on my system

```
     - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 
     - SQL Server 2017
     - Visual Studio 2015
```

When I tried to open SSMS for the first time, it asked me for the "Server Name" when I surfed I came to know that I have to check the instance name in Configuration manager-->Sql Services, but I couldn't find any services running in Configuration Manager, it is showing "There are no items to show"

Secondly, I also tried giving the permissions to my SQL Server services as mentioned in article [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2492/why-is-sql-server-configuration-manager-missing-services/),  but couldn't solve my issue.

Also I tried to check find the SQL Server instance name using the `sqlcmd -L` command, but it didn't show any servers, even though SQL Server is already installed.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image: No Server Server Instance Found although Server is installed]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i am not an expert here but I would try the two values that you found.  It seems it should either be DMRDBILCND7288L or it should be SQLEXPRESS

Comment: If the SQL Server Configuration Manager doesn't display any services, see that you have started the right version. The file name is SQLServerManager<version>.msc and should be in \Windows\System32 dir. There might be several, so pick the latest.

Comment: You should also use a way more [recent SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) version if you're on SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1):

SQLExpress is installed as a named instance. Try connecting to  `<server name>\SQLEXPRESS`

Or `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` will work as well.